# postgres: How to skip the fist and the last row of a queryset in a for-loop?

Tags: postgresql, for-loop, stored-procedures, skip

In a function I'm looping over the all rows a select statement returns. I want to **skip the fist and the last row**. How could I do this?

```
...
  FOR arow IN
    SELECT (dp).path[1] As index, 
           ST_AsText((dp).geom) As wktnode, 
           (dp).geom As vertex
      FROM (SELECT 
          ST_DumpPoints(
              ST_Segmentize(NEW.the_geom,
                  -- the max length of the segment 
                  ST_Length(
                      NEW.the_geom
                  )/NEW.dist_calc_pnts
              )
          ) AS dp
    ) As foo
    LOOP

      test_me := arow.index;
      IF NOT (ST_Equals(arow.vertex, ST_StartPoint(NEW.the_geom))
                      OR
             ST_Equals(arow.vertex, ST_EndPoint(NEW.the_geom))) THEN

      RAISE NOTICE 'Calling update_pntzzz(%)', test_me;
      INSERT INTO 
         pntzzz(onedee_id, the_geom)
      VALUES(NEW.id, arow.vertex);
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
...
```

As I said, I do not need the result from first and the last iteration but I'm struggling on how to implement this. Right now the `if` statement checks whether the geometry of the current row is identical to the start or endpoint of the original line geometry - a rather expensive check.

Comment: You could use OFFSET 1 ROW in your SELECT to skip the first one and a window function to get the current row number and the total count to check for the last one. I don't remember the syntax exactly but I think it was something like SELECT …, count(*), row_number() OVER () FROM …

Comment: usually when you select , loop and insert that can be achieved in a single query.

Comment: @e4c5 I'm always happy to learn! Would you share you knowledge with me?

Comment: Postgresql can handle complex queries really really well. As a rule of thumb almost all SELECT - LOOP - INSERTs can be converted to INSERT SELECT queries. in some cases where the query is hard to write you can get help from Common Table Expressions.

Comment: @e4c5 Thanks! I managed to insert the new records without the ``for``-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some sample code to show how to skip the first and the last element in a loop.

It should be simple to adapt it to your use case.

```
DO $$DECLARE
   counter integer := 0;
   i integer;
   old_i integer;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
      counter := counter + 1;
      IF counter > 2 THEN
         -- processing of old_i goes here
         RAISE WARNING 'Processing row %', old_i;
      END IF;

      old_i := i;
   END LOOP;
END;$$;
```

Comment: how does this skip the last element?

Comment: Try it out :^) An element is processed during the next iteration (hence the `old_i` variable), so the last element is never processed.

Comment: Ok, I see. So instead of using arow in your ``if`` part you would use ``old_i``

Comment: Yeah. For you, it would probably be `old_arow` which is assigned with `old_arow := arow`.